# Runtime Error 424 Object Required in Vb6

Tags: vb6

I am new to Vb,

i am getting error in my source code,

here is my code snippet,

```
Dim a,b as integer 
  a=val (txtf.Text)
  b=val (txts.Text)
    if(a>b)then
       txtr=a
    else
      txtr=b
   end if 
end sub
```

***ERROR*: Runtime Error 424 Object Required:**

**any help will be appriciated.**

Comment: Where does the error occur? Which line?

Comment: Are you using "option explicit on" ? Recommend you do.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to know the datatype of `txtf`, `txts` and `txtr` -- are they textbox controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safer to type

```
Dim a as Integer
Dim b as integer
```

or

```
Dim a as integer,b as integer
```

This might be the case of the error

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined textr . Do that and your prob will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify txtr as txtr.txt instead it read txtr as an object...

Answer (score 0):

Error that I found You should separate a,b; instead write is as:

Dim a as integer,b as integer or

Dim a as integer
Dim b as integer